# Dart - convert string type to datetime type with dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, datetime, converters

how to convert string to datetime format in dart?
please note the day and month lose a 0

```
String date = '2022-5-24';
 DateTime parsedDate =  DateTime.parse('$date 00:00:00.000');
```

log

```
E/flutter (12187): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants to convert a date in string format to some other string format first use DateTime.parse("2022-05-24") then pass it to DateFormat("date pattern").format() like

```
dateFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.parse("2022-05-24"));
```

You can use intl.dart to formate any date . Here is a simple example of this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
String dateFormate;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
dateFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.parse("2022-05-24"));
return Container(
  child: Text(dateFormate),
);}}
```

Comment: how to convert "2022-5-24" to "2022-05-24" , or "2022-10-4" to "2022-10-04"

Comment: There is only one way that is split your string to 3 part , and check if part 2 and 3 lenght == 1 then + "0" before it @HusamuldeenAbdlrahman